# What Is The Path Where Apache Is Located?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, osx-server, apache

When I check logs (Apache, Ruby on Rails) it appears that my development Mac Mini Server is being scanned.  I would like to install mod_security.  I'm currently running the latest version of Mavericks but plan to install Yosemite within couple of days.  I use Apache 2.2.26.

Where are the Apache modules located on the Mac Mini Server in Mavericks and Yosemite?

If there is a better way to protect my service, such as turning on the Firewall in System Preferences, I'm open to that.  I just don't know enough about how to set that up where I can do what I normally do and add my websites to it.

Comment: Check `/private/etc/apache2` for a `mods-available` folder. Enabled modules are symlinked to the `mods-enabled` folder in the `apache2` directory.

Comment: I just checked.  The only folders in /private/etc/apache2 are extra, original, other and users.  None of them have a mods-available folder.  I also did a search but did not find mods-available.  Can I create a folder named mods-available and proceed?

Comment: On OS X they don't make a "mods-available" and "mods-enabled" folder by default. They just have a much more basic directory layout. When I first set up a Linux server and saw "sites-available" etc., I was like, WTH is all this?! But yeah it's just a different set of defaults. I kinda wish Apple would standardize the setup of alot of this to be the same as Linux just so thisnkind of confusion might be avoided :D

Comment: @LightBeCorp I would not try adding the folders. In pre-Lion versions of Server, enabling mods was done in Server Admin. I have no idea of where they've moved it to, or if it's accessible at all now.

Comment: https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/#/apd5B742D97-6A85-49E4-A0CE-9472EE22CAB4 may be a little help.

Answer (score 1):

The default location is:

```
/usr/libexec/apache2/
```